# How do I enable auto-save after finishing a game in FIFA 14?

Tags: fifa-14

I have just started playing Fifa 14 career mode and I have played Fifa 13 career mode and there was an option in Fifa 13 where you could automatically save when you finished a game. I can't seem to find this option in Fifa 14. Does this option exist in Fifa 14? If so, where can I find this option?

Answer (score 1):

FIFA 14 does not ask you for autosave option because it is already on. It saves your progress match by match.

Comment: Not true. I finished a match and stopped playing. Went back on career mode and had to play it again.

Comment: Did you simmed match? Because it doesn't save if you're simming games, it does autosave if you actually play a match.

Comment: @Loko it does say in the manual, at least for the XBox 360 version, that it uses autosave. It doesn't specifically say where, but after a match would seem like a logical place to autosave.

Comment: i didnt simulated a match

Comment: Auto save is automatically on since game's first run and it tells you it's on in the start screen. You may have disabled it for some reason.

Comment: @Mr.White Not that I know of...